# SSR on Firebase Hosting with GC Functions not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting

Ok so this is my folder Structure

[image]

So here is the Functions Index File:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt')

const app = express()

const config = {
  dev: false,
  buildDir: 'nuxt',
  build: {
    publicPath: '/'
  }
}
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

function handleRequest (req, res) {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200')
  nuxt.renderRoute('/').then(result => {
    res.send(result.html)
  }).catch(e => {
    res.send(e)
  })
}

app.get('*', handleRequest)
exports.nuxtApp = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

But all I get when visiting the Url is `"{"code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND"}`
(after deploying)

All i did in the `nuxt.config.js` is just telling it to make the build directory into the nuxt folder in the functions folder

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nuxtApp"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When testing locally with Firebase Serve it works but it only renders the base url `/` and nothing else and also I have no Static Assets like my scss files or the app manifest.

Comment: Just hit the same issue, looks like we both followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYUWsjUxxUQ&t=896s would be nice if someone has an answer

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Firebase functions and Nuxtjs.

Comment: @SzaboCsaba Im hosting on Heroku right now since the setup was really messy for the Firebase Hosting + Nuxt also the cold start times of functions made page visits sometimes slow

Answer (score 3):

After a few days of debugging I found a solution.

At first, you have to extend your error logging, so you can see the stack-trace:

```
console.error(e)
res.send(e)
```

My errors were:

**error#1** `firebase` package was not installed in my functions folder, so I had to install it with `npm install --save firebase` in the `functions` directory. The overall `firebase` package is not required by Cloud Functions, however it's needed for my `nuxt` project for `firestore` usage

**error#2** You could get an error like `firebaseApp.firestore is not a function`. It's due to a wrong import of firebase to you could function. I found the solution for this problem [here](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/513)

I change this import:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

To this:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore'
```

After solving these two errors, my NuxtJs app worked well with Firebase Cloud Functions.